# Baking numerous simulations using FLIP FLUIDS

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm encountering a challenge with my current project involving fluid simulations using Flip Fluids. I need to run multiple simulations within the same blend file for different shots, each at distinct points on the timeline.

However, I've hit a roadblock as I attempted to add another domain for the second simulation. I received an error stating that only one domain is permitted per blend file.

To illustrate, let's say I need simulations for frames 100-200 and 300-400. How can I bake these simulations independently so that the first ends at frame 200 and the second begins at frame 300, without affecting each other?

I'd greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions. Thank you!"\

Answer (score 1):

just create the first fluid simulation until you are happy. Then select your inflow object -> file -> export (e.g. alembic)

then delete everything and create your 2nd fluid simulation (change the start frame in the domain). Export that too.

Now delete everything and import both alembic files. You might have to adjust your timeline.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll try that
But that means I can just use a separate blend file to sim all the fluid I want and then import it back to the main file.
I'm guessing this also helps with file optimization and viewport playback, right?
Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, so I tried the alembic file export, and it worked to a certain extent.
Upon reimporting the file back, the simulation kept stuttering, disappearing, and reappearing in the scene.
Any tips that could help?

Comment: You may want to use the **FLIP Fluids Sidebar > Command Line Tools > Alembic Export** operator tool instead of the regular exporter. There is a current bug in Blender that can cause these incorrect frame exports and this operator works around these issues: https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/wiki/Helper-Menu-Settings#command-line-alembic-export

Comment: Alright, I'll try that.
Thanks